# Is there a widget that can play videos in Android?

Tags: android, video, android-widget

I want to play videos in my Android application, is there a widget that can do this?

Answer (score 0):

If you want play video from url ,then You can use android's default player for play video.

Uri u1 = Uri.parse("URL to video file");
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
i.setData(u);
i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(i);